# Formulating a pipeline with several variables

Tags: linear-programming

The question

[image]

I have one constraint as  number of faculty signing a contract of length r, i am unsure what other constraints i can make to complete the program. Would it be the amount of years worked?

Comment: Do you need any further help?

Comment: @callculus Yes if possible

Comment: How can I help? You can leave a comment below my answer. Is the content of the answer comprehensible?

Comment: @callculus thank you, so would I have 4 different constraints, one for each year ?

Comment: Also how would I formulate the minimising function